# How to skip or delay events in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Here is a script that I am using for my experiment.
The objects hear 3 different tones, each representing different amount of reward. So   when tone 1 comes on, there is no reward, and when tone 2 and 3 come on and the object triggers the `photobeam(pb_broken)`, the rewards will be given.

The problem is that sometimes the object receives reward without even hearing the tone because they're near photobeam thus triggering it, and causing it to release reward.

I want to prevent that from happening and I'm not sure how to do so.
here are my options:

1. if photobeam 1 is triggered (there are 2 photobeams) before tones, then skip the tone, and proceed with experiment (don't play that tone again and go on to the next whenever it  was suppose to come on originally)
2. if photobeam 1 is triggered before the reward tones (2 and 3) then skip the tone (like above)
3. if pb 1 is broken, then delay the tone by 1 second, thus delaying everything by 1 second, and still ending at 1200 seconds. this would be the ideal case.

Here's my code:

```
clear all;

%%
% Set-up DAQ with an output and input session
global outputSession; % this will control the feeders
outputSession = daq.createSession('ni');
outputSession.addDigitalChannel('Dev2', 'Port1/Line0:1', 'OutputOnly');
outputSession.outputSingleScan([0 0]); % set everything to 0 to start

global inputSession; % this reads from the photobeams
inputSession = daq.createSession('ni');
inputSession.addDigitalChannel('Dev2', 'Port1/Line5:6', 'InputOnly');

global leverSession; % read from levers: note, scan returns 1 if not pressed, empty if pressed!
leverSession = daq.createSession('ni');
leverSession.addDigitalChannel('Dev2', 'Port1/Line2', 'InputOnly');

%% intitialize variables, draw status figure etc.
global target_rewarded; % needs to be global so functions can reset it
target_rewarded = [0 0]; % no targets (receptacles) armed to start

% track times and IDs of photobeam breaks
EventLogSize = 10000;
eventLog.pb_broken_time = nan(EventLogSize,1);
eventLog.pb_broken_id = nan(EventLogSize,1);
pb_counter = 1;

% times and IDs of feeders
eventLog.reward_time = nan(500,1);
eventLog.reward_id = nan(500,1);
reward_counter = 1;

eventLog.mistake_time = nan(500,1);
eventLog.mistake_id = nan(500,1);
mistake_counter = 1;

%%% generate trial start times %%%
sound_on = 0;
trial_count = 1;

%%% generate trial list %%%

trial_block = [1 1 2 2 3 3]; % permute block and repeat
eventLog.trial_list = [];
for iBlock = 1:50
   
    eventLog.trial_list = cat(2,eventLog.trial_list,trial_block(randperm(length(trial_block))));
    
end

%%% SET UP TIMES OF CUE (TONE) ONSET HERE
maxTrials = 500;
mean_ITI = 20;
SD_ITI = 3;

eventLog.trial_times = mean_ITI.*ones(maxTrials,1);
trial_SD = SD_ITI.*randn(maxTrials,1);
eventLog.trial_times = eventLog.trial_times + trial_SD;

eventLog.trial_times = cumsum(eventLog.trial_times);

%%% set up sounds %%%
outputID = 10; % which sound connection on computer to use

duration = 7; % in seconds
samplesPerSecond = 22050; % the bit rate of the tone
tvec = 0:1/samplesPerSecond:duration;

% 1: 2kHz tone, on/off at 10Hz
s1 = sin(2*pi*2000*tvec);
s1 = s1.*square(2*pi*10*tvec);
s1 = 0.2.*s1;

% 2: white noise
s2 = rand(size(tvec));
s2 = 0.2*((s2.*2)-1);

% 4: 8kHz tone, sinewave amplitude-modulated at 2Hz
s3 = sin(2*pi*8000*tvec);
modl = 0.5*(sin(2*pi*2*tvec)+1);
s3 = s3.*modl;

s3 = 0.5.*s3;

tone1 = audioplayer(s1, samplesPerSecond, 16, outputID);
set(tone1,'StopFcn',@reset_rewards); % set it up so that if the tone ends, rewards are reset

tone2 = audioplayer(s2, samplesPerSecond, 16, outputID);
set(tone2,'StopFcn',@reset_rewards); % set it up so that if the tone ends, rewards are reset

tone3 = audioplayer(s3, samplesPerSecond, 16, outputID);
set(tone3,'StopFcn',@reset_rewards); % set it up so that if the tone ends, rewards are reset

sound_timer = [];

%%% tone-to-pellet mapping
tone_to_pellets = [0 2 5];

correct_pb = 1; % which photobeam is rewarded
correct_feeder = 2; % which feeder to use

%%% initialize main timer and photobeam status %%%
start_timer = tic; % call as t_elapsed = toc(start_timer);
t_elapsed = 0;
max_time = 1200; % in seconds

pb_broken = [];
previous_broken = 0;

%%% make task window %%%
fs = 18;
f1_handle = figure(1);
t_handle = title('Task starting...'); set(t_handle,'FontSize',fs);

status_handle = text(0,0.8,sprintf('Correct trials %d, Incorrect trials %d',reward_counter-1,mistake_counter-1)); set(status_handle,'FontSize',fs);
axis off;

%% run task

while t_elapsed < max_time
    
    % update figure text,time
    set(t_handle,'String',sprintf('t %.2f, pb %d, target %s',t_elapsed,pb_broken,num2str(target_rewarded)));
    drawnow;
    
    t_elapsed = toc(start_timer);
    
    % check if any photobeams are broken
    pb_broken = pb_scan(inputSession);
    
    n_broken = numel(pb_broken);
    if n_broken > 0 % do something potentially
        
        % check
        if n_broken > 1
            disp('WARNING: multiple photobeams broken');
            pb_broken = pb_broken(1);
        end
        
        if pb_broken == previous_broken % no change, do nothing
            continue;
        end
        
        % log this: it's a new photobeam break
        eventLog.pb_broken_time(pb_counter) = t_elapsed;
        eventLog.pb_broken_id(pb_counter) = pb_broken;
        pb_counter = pb_counter + 1;
        
        disp(sprintf('*** Photobeam %d broken ***',pb_broken));
              
        if any(target_rewarded > 0) % reward active, maybe dispense pellet
            
            if pb_broken == correct_pb
                             
                disp('*** CORRECT POKE ***');
                
                switch eventLog.trial_list(trial_count-1) % check what trial it is
                    
                    case 1
                        disp(sprintf('Dispensed %d pellets',tone_to_pellets(1)));
                        dispensePellets(correct_feeder,tone_to_pellets(1));
                        stop(tone1);
                    case 2
                        disp(sprintf('Dispensed %d pellets',tone_to_pellets(2)));
                        dispensePellets(correct_feeder,tone_to_pellets(2));
                        stop(tone2);
                    case 3
                        disp(sprintf('Dispensed %d pellets',tone_to_pellets(3)));
                        dispensePellets(correct_feeder,tone_to_pellets(3));
                        stop(tone3);
                end
                
                target_rewarded = [0 0];
                
                eventLog.reward_time(reward_counter) = t_elapsed;
                eventLog.reward_id(reward_counter) = tone_to_pellets(eventLog.trial_list(trial_count-1));
                reward_counter = reward_counter + 1;
                
                disp(sprintf('Logged %d pellets rewarded',tone_to_pellets(eventLog.trial_list(trial_count-1))));
                
                set(status_handle,'String',sprintf('Correct trials %d, Incorrect trials %d',reward_counter-1,mistake_counter-1));
                
            else % wrong receptacle
                
                if ~poked_this_trial
                    disp('*** ACTIVE CUE, INCORRECT POKE ***');
                    mistake_counter = mistake_counter + 1;
                    poked_this_trial = 1;
                end
                
            end
            
            
        else % no reward active, do nothing
            
            disp('*** INACTIVE CUE, INCORRECT POKE ***');
            %mistake_counter = mistake_counter + 1;
            
        end
        
    end % of photobeam broken loop
    
    
    % check if a new trial (sound) is starting
    if t_elapsed > eventLog.trial_times(trial_count)
        
        switch eventLog.trial_list(trial_count) % check what trial it is
            
            case 1
                play(tone1);
                target_rewarded = [0 tone_to_pellets(1)];
            case 2
                play(tone2);
                target_rewarded = [0 tone_to_pellets(2)];
            case 3
                play(tone3);
                target_rewarded = [0 tone_to_pellets(3)];
        end
        sound_timer = tic;
          
        trial_count = trial_count + 1;
        
        poked_this_trial = 0;
        
        disp(sprintf('New trial started (%d pellets): updated trial count is %d',target_rewarded(2),trial_count));
    end
    
    % check if we need to stop sound
    if ~isempty(sound_timer) & toc(sound_timer) > duration
       
        switch eventLog.trial_list(trial_count - 1)
            
            case 1
                stop(tone1)
            case 2
                stop(tone2)
            case 3
                stop(tone3)
        end
        
    end
    
    previous_broken = pb_broken;
    
end % of main while loop
```

Comment: Don't precompute the times for the start of the trials.  Instead, in each loop you can check the current time against a range of conditions and decide whether it's time to start the next one.  If it is, populate the trial start/stop times and start the sound.  This way, you can check the time of the last beam-break, and if it's too recent, don't start the trial.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a complicated problem to troubleshoot without hands on, and less of a programming and more of an experimental design question.

You may want to ensure that no photobeams are interrupted before starting a new tone, perhaps by substituting

```
 if t_elapsed > eventLog.trial_times(trial_count)
```

with

```
if t_elapsed > eventLog.trial_times(trial_count) & ~n_broken
```

You could alternately add a while loop at the end of the pb obstruct check statement that makes sure no new event occurs for 1 sec, before exiting the if statement and proceeding. But then you also have to check the sound and possibly terminate it before exiting that loop.

As a final alternative, running a variety of controls (which I'm sure you are running), for instance an experiment without rewards, should serve to check the likelihood of random obstructions.

I am not sure what kind of constraints you have requiring keeping to a tight trial schedule, but as another comment mentions it may be best to record the time for events but allow arbitrary time for the system to "clear" before proceeding with the new trial.